# How to put left-justified text next to gathered equations

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, gather

Minimal example

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    x+(y+z) = (x+y)+z
\end{equation*}

\begin{gather}
\tag*{This pushes it} 
    x+(y+z) = (x+y)+z \\
\tag*{This doesn't} 
    x+(y+z) = (x+y)+z
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Looking for a way to put text to the left of gathered equations without
pushing them out of the center.

**Edit.**
The equations should be centered but not aligned.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want, but I don't think you mean for your text to be a `tag`. If you want the gathered equations aligned with the equation above, I suggest using `flalign` together with `\text`. To keep the text from pushing the equation, put it in an `\rlap`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    x+(y+z) = (x+y)+z
\end{equation*}
\begin{flalign*}
  &&  x+(y+z) &= (x+y)+z& \\ &\rlap{\text{This doesn't push it}} & x+(y+z) &= (x+y)+z \\ &\rlap{\text{Neither does this}} & x+(y+z) &= (x+y)+z
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\rlap` fixes the problem. In my real document the equations don't align nicely. It looks better for them all to be centered. So I might have to use `gather` with `tag*`. Would be nice to not use `tag*` in case I also need equation numbers.